# How to 'switch' based on keys contained in a dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I want to execute different branches based on what keys a dictionary contains, here's some code you can paste into a playground that shows what I currently do:

```
let dict1 = ["a" : 1, "thingy" : 2]
let dict2 = ["b" : 3, "wotsit" : 4]
let dict = dict1 // Change this line to see different outcomes

if  let valueA = dict["a"],
    let thingy = dict["thingy"] {
        // Code for type with "a" and "thingy" keys
        println("a/thingy")
} else if   let valueB = dict["b"],
            let wotsit = dict["wotsit"] {
        // Code for type with "b" and "wotsit" keys
        println("b/wotsit")
}
```

However, I think this would be more elegantly expressed as a switch statement - something like this:

```
let dict1 = ["a" : 1, "thingy" : 2]
let dict2 = ["b" : 3, "wotsit" : 4]
let dict = dict1 // Change this line to see different outcomes

switch dict {
case    let a = dict["a"],
        let thingy = dict["thingy"]:
    // Code for type with "a" and "thingy" keys
    println("a/thingy")
case    let b = dict["b"],
        let wotsit = dict["wotsit"]:
    // Code for type with "b" and "wotsit" keys
    println("b/wotsit")
default:
    break
}
```

I have tried the above and various other attempts to express this logic in a switch but couldn't make it work. So how could I do this in a `switch` (or is this misguided in some way)?

#### Background:

The dictionaries are actually SwiftyJSON `JSON` objects loaded from JSON data, and I want to infer the 'type' of object these JSON structures represent, from what keys they contain - if they don't contain all the right keys for a particular object they won't attempt to load as that type. I could add a `"type"` to each JSON structure and `switch` based on that value, but I'd prefer to automatically infer their type from the keys as I currently do.

Comment: Don't you just want to iterate over the keys, and check if they are in your dic:

    `for (myKey,myValue) in toppings {
    println("\(myKey) \t \(myValue)")
}`

Comment: I don’t think you’ll get a better result from `switch`, but it may help your sense of elegance with the `if` statement to know you don’t need the second let i.e. `if let valueA = dict["a"], thingy = dict["thingy"] {`

Comment: The part you describe in the background _might_ be more nicely expressed with `map` or `flatMap` but you’d need to give a bit more detail on your goal.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity I prefer being explicit with the `let` mostly because it looks neater and more readable. Putting the different assignments on different lines is more readable and without the `let` on subsequent lines it's not as clear (visually) that those lines are doing the same type of thing.

Comment: Well there’s no accounting for taste, but I would say that large quantities of syntactic ceremony like this are generally antithetical to Swift.